# Custom NavigationBar iOS 5 compatibility

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I was trying to implement a project with custom navigation bar; however, the following code:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

// Set the navigation bar background
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height + 1)];
}
@end
```

is not working for iOS 5. I am using Xcode 4.2.

Question: How can I implement a custom navigation bar without compromising the use of the code above for earlier versions (< iOS 5)?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it...this might help others implementing this.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

// Set the navigation bar background
- (UIImage *)barBackground{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height + 1)];
    return image;
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview{
    // Applies to iOS 5
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
    {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[self barBackground] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
}

// This doesn't work on iOS5 but is needed for iOS4 and earlier
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Draw the image
    [[self barBackground] drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```